# Count of fields that have a number

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I have a series of SQLs that output similar results, but have slightly different purposes. One of the fields in all of them is oper_ID. oper_ID can contain letters and numbers. Admin oper_ID's do NOT have numbers in them. Client oper_ID's have numbers at the end. For example. Admin: johnsmith, Client: mikejones12345.

I've been commenting out/in the following lines in my sql depending on which I wanted to get.

```
--AND REGEXP_LIKE(ded.oper_ID, '[[:digit:]]') -- return only client userIDs    
--AND NOT REGEXP_LIKE(ded.oper_ID, '[[:digit:]]') -- return only admin userIDs
```

I want to simplify this so I don't have to run it twice to count the admins and then count the clients. oper_ID is in the select statement in all the SQLs.

What would be a good way to either create a count of each one or at least put a "admin" or "client" in a new column next to each record?

Any ideas?

Thanks for the help!!
Craig

Comment: You should show the results you want.  Also, a simplified version of your query would be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you just want conditional aggregation or `group by`.

For instance:

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN REGEXP_LIKE(ded.oper_ID, '[[:digit:]]') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as clients,
       SUM(CASE WHEN NOT REGEXP_LIKE(ded.oper_ID, '[[:digit:]]') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as admins
. . .
```

Comment: That worked, but needed to add a close parentheses  after '[[:digit:]]'